# Optimise simple rule-matching logic

Tags: java, match, rule-engine

I have a simple algorithm for some rule-matching logic and would like to see if there is a way to optimise it.

The problem is as follows - I have a set of rules, and I need to determine for each incoming record, which rule (if any) matches the record. The record is essentially a map of string attributes to string values. The rule consists of an integer id and a list of conditions. Each condition has an attribute, an operator (IN or NOT_IN) and a set of string values.

So a sample rule might look something like the following:

```
{
    id: "1",
    conditions: [
        {
            attribute: "firstname",
            operator: "IN",
            values: ["Jon", "Fred"]
        },{
            attribute: "surname",
            operator: "NOT_IN",
            values: ["Smith"]
        }
    ]
}
```

The above rule would match any record where record.get("firstname") is either "Jon" or "Fred", and record.get("surname") is either null or not "Smith".

The rule matching logic when applied to a single record is as follows:

1. Iterate through each rule:

   1. Iterate through each condition for the rule:

      1. Lookup the condition attribute from the record attribute map.
      2. If the condition operator is IN then apply the following check:

         1. If the map contains the attribute and the lookup value is in the list of condition values then the condition passes, otherwise if fails.
      3. Else, if the condition operator is NOT_IN then apply the following check:

         1. If the map does not contain the attribute, or the lookup valu is not in the list of condition values then the condition passes, otherwise if fails.
   2. If all conditions pass then the rule is a match and no futher rules are considered.

If it's not clear, the order of the rules in the list is important, as the first rule that matches will be chosen.

I've included some Java code below that implements the Rules data model and the above algorithm.

The above logic is relatively simple to implement, but it involves iterating through the rules for each record. My question is whether there's a more efficient algorithm.

Some more data points:

1. The rules are essentially static.
2. There are around 2 billion records to process.
3. The records will arrive in batches of varying sizes, but typically 100,000 - 1,000,000.
4. The attributes are known in advance - there are around 500 in total, however the rules only use a relatively small subset - prob no more than 20.
5. The attribute values are not generally known in advance.
6. Each condition will typically contain a small number of values - usually no more than 6.
7. The conditions that comprise a rule will each use different attributes - i.e. you would never get a rule with two or more conditions using the same attribute.
8. The number of conditions comprising a rule is typically small - usually no more than 4.

To optimise the algorithm I looked at ways to pre-compile the rules into a data structure that might speed up the rule processing. At first I thought a decision tree structure might be more optimal, but it's not immediately clear how to construct one, as each rule may be testing different sets of attributes. Another approach I thought about involved encoding each rule as a number, perhaps as a bitmap or a hash code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class RulesTest {
    
    // Data model.

    enum Operator {IN, NOT_IN}

    record Condition(String attribute, Operator operator, Set<String> values) {}

    record Rule(int id, List<Condition> conditions) {}

    // Test data.
    
    private static final List<Rule> TEST_RULES = List.of(
            new Rule(
                    1,
                    List.of(
                            new Condition("B", Operator.IN, Set.of("b1", "b2")),
                            new Condition("C", Operator.IN, Set.of("c2", "c4"))
                    )
            ), new Rule(
                    2,
                    List.of(
                            new Condition("A", Operator.IN, Set.of("a1", "a3")),
                            new Condition("C", Operator.NOT_IN, Set.of("c1", "c4")),
                            new Condition("D", Operator.IN, Set.of("d1", "d2", "d3"))
                    )
            ), new Rule(
                    3,
                    List.of(
                            new Condition("B", Operator.NOT_IN, Set.of("b1", "b4")),
                            new Condition("D", Operator.NOT_IN, Set.of("d1", "d2")),
                            new Condition("E", Operator.IN, Set.of("e1"))
                    )
            )
    );

    // Matching logic.
    private static OptionalInt match(List<Rule> rules, Map<String, String> attrValues) {
        for (Rule rule : rules) {
            final boolean pass = rule.conditions
                    .stream()
                    .allMatch(condition -> {
                        final String attrValue = attrValues.get(condition.attribute);
                        return (attrValue != null && condition.values().contains(attrValue))
                                == (condition.operator == Operator.IN);
                    });
            if (pass) {
                return OptionalInt.of(rule.id);
            }
        }

        return OptionalInt.empty();
    }

    private static void test(List<Rule> rules, Map<String, String> attrValues) {
        final OptionalInt optRuleId = match(rules, attrValues);

        System.out.println(attrValues + " -> " + optRuleId);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            final Map<String, String> attrValues = Map.of(
                    "A", "a1",
                    "B", "b1",
                    "C", "c1"
            );

            test(TEST_RULES, attrValues);
        }

        {
            final Map<String, String> attrValues = Map.of(
                    "B", "b2",
                    "C", "c2"
            );

            test(TEST_RULES, attrValues);
        }

        {
            final Map<String, String> attrValues = Map.of(
                    "A", "a3",
                    "C", "c3",
                    "D", "d3"
            );

            test(TEST_RULES, attrValues);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your code works, but you're just looking for ways to optimise it, then this question might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How does the attribute values loaded in the memory? Is it dynamically getting refreshed based on some criteria?

Comment: @AmitJain The attribute value map is populated in memory incrementally by various pieces of enrichment logic.

Comment: @QBrute This code is demo code and would be considered too theoretical on Code Review.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating over the rules, we can iterate over the attributes and run only those rules which checks for the specific attribute.

If you build the map for the rules which can be applied for the attribute(`attributeRuleMap`), you can improve the performance a little bit.

Something like below

```
class Rule {
    int id;
    Map<String, Condition> conditionsMap = new HashMap<>();

    public Rule(int id, List<Condition> conditions) {
        this.id = id;
        conditions.forEach(condition -> {
            attributeRuleMap.computeIfAbsent(condition.attribute, x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(id);
            conditionsMap.put(condition.attribute, condition);
        });
        ruleMap.put(id, this);
    }
}
```

`conditionsMap` is for accessing only the conditions for a specific attribute we are checking the rule.

Then your match function can be something like below

```
private static List<Integer> match(Map<String, String> attrValues) {
    List<Integer> rules = new ArrayList<>();
    attrValues.forEach((key, value) ->
                           attributeRuleMap.get(key)
                                           .forEach(rule -> {
                                                        Condition condition = ruleMap.get(rule).conditionsMap.get(key);
                                                        if (condition.values.contains(value) && condition.operator == Operator.IN) {
                                                            rules.add(rule);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                           ));
    return rules;

}
```

Comment: Not sure what your code is doing. I don't think it would work, and even if it did I don't think it would be faster than the simple algorithm.